# Spring Framework Maven Difference

Tags: java, spring, maven, settings, pom.xml

I am currently involved in a project managed by maven and the project structure is a mess. So I tried to update the pom files and settings.xml first.
However after I switched in settings.xml:

```
        <repository>
            <id>Spring IO Releases</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>Spring IO Snapshots</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
```

to:

```
<repository>
                    <id>Spring IO Snapshots</id>
                    <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>Spring IO Releases</id>
                    <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
```

And changed my dependency from:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>org.springframework.XXX</artifactId>
   <version>${spring-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-XXX</artifactId>
   <version>${spring-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

However it didn't work. What is the difference between these two dependencies?
I have checked inside the Jar files and only obvious thing is springframework.XXX artifacts are build 1 month before spring-XXX artifact contents.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code doesn't work? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Which Version of spring do you use? The main difference is the artefact Name. But a description of "didn't work" was very helpful

Comment: You should remove the snapshot repositories. Normaly you only Need the release Versions of spring. This you can get from the Standard maven repository. So also the spring.io release repository is not needed